# Get the process id from ps -ef grep (or Stop an application before removing it)

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, grep, rpm

I have an rpm and I want on uninstall to check if my application is running and if it is stop it before running the uninstall.
My service runs under a specific user.
How can I do this using bash in rpm spec?
I.e. how can I know my service is running so that I can stop it?

**Update:**
If I do `ps -ef|grep myUser` how can I get the process id from the result so that I can do `kill -9`?

Comment: _Don't_ `kill -9`. Just `kill`. `kill -9` is not nice, and not even helpful in most respects (might leave file descriptors hanging, create zombies, etc.). At least be sure you know _exactly_ what `kill -9` means before using it in a routine way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
ps -U someUserName -o pid,comm | awk '/someProcessName/{print $1}'
```

(edited my answer and took the above line from my answer to [your related question](https://superuser.com/questions/406540/simulate-pgrep-using-plain-grep)) or similar [1], or even better

```
pgrep -u myuser mybinaryname
```

to get the process id, or *even* simpler

```
pkill -u myuser mybinaryname
```

to directly kill the process.

Do some tests to determine the binary name and make sure it doesn't collide with other processes though.

(`pgrep` and `pkill` are most likely already installed on your system. Otherwise they are (on Debian based systems) in the package `procps`).

---

Note that a normal user most probably doesn't have privileges to kill other users' processes, so e.g. `pkill mybinaryname` need to be run with elevated privileges. It sounds like a script run by root (since it is uninstalling programs), so this might not be an issue.

---

[1]: `awk` picks first non-blank field by collapsing leading spaces which will appear if pid<10000 (on my system, since pidmax is 32767), which would confuse e.g. `cut`.

Comment: But why binary name and not user name?

Comment: Do you have many users running the process, and only want to kill a the specific instance of a certain user? It sounds like you just want to kill the process, no matter who owns it. I will add to my answer that you might not (probably not) have privileges to kill other users' processes like this, so you might need to run it via `sudo` or similar.

Comment: The process runs only under 1 specific user and there is 1 process running.The root will do this

Comment: Then you don't need to explicitly restrict it a single user, but you *can* do it with `pgrep -u myUser myBinaryName`. I can add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps wp PID|grep PID
```

You ca do it without the grep - you will find with grep you remove the header..