# Simulate pgrep using plain grep

Tags: linux, bash, script, grep

How can I do `pgrep -U someUserName` using just `ps` and `grep`? I.e. not count on `pgrep` being set in a system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
ps -U someUserName -o pid,comm | awk '/someProcessName/{print $1}'
```

Note that you might get multiple process ids as output if there are multiple processes running that matches user and process name.

The `ps` output is really made for readable presentation, not for being processed like this. There are other tools to give more low level access to the process list in a format better suited for scripting, just such as `pgrep`, Perl/Python/... libraries and so on.

---

To do it using *only* `ps` and `grep` as you ask for, one could do

```
ps -U someUserName -o pid,comm | grep 'someProcessName' | grep -oE '^ *([^ ]*)'
```

This will include leading white space, but that should be a problem in application, e.g.

```
for i in $(ps -U someUserName -o pid,comm | grep 'someProcessName' | grep -oE '^ *([^ ]*)'); do
    kill $i
done
```

should work.

But as I said, `pkill` is a more correct and robust way, and should be widely available.

Comment: `awk` is a better bet than `sed` or `cut` for picking bits out of the output of `ps`.

Comment: @Blrfl: true, it collapses white space nicely. Will update the answer.

Comment: One could also use `awk '/name/{print $1}'` directly.

Comment: @grawity: also true, one more fix. As a sidenote I didn't really want to use `sed` or `awk` to begin with since the poster wanted a platform agnostic solution (on platforms where `pgrep` and `pkill` might not be available), and I believe `pgrep`/`pkill` are more or less just as widely available as `sed`/`awk` (which was the advise on the posters original question).

Comment: `awk` is specified in POSIX, so odds are good that if you have a system with `grep`, you'll have it.  Same for `sed`.